# Look Up - AppleScript command

Tags: applescript, spotlight, look-up

Is there an apple script command for the *"Look Up"* action/service?
If not, what would be a decent way to mimic it?

If you don't know what I'm talking about it's the popover when you three-finger click some thing, or select some text and select *Look Up "some text"* in the contextual menu.
[image: Look Up]

Comment: Cmd/Ctrl/D mimics it pretty well already ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I suppose, that works, but not a big fan of mimicking keystrokes. Thanks for pointing that out anyways.